# Firebase snapshot to label in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uilabel

I'm new to Firebase, but learning quickly. This question has eluded me, though, and I've spent the past three days looking for an answer, and I'm sure it's a simple solution that I'm just overlooking. I want to return a value from my Firebase database to populate a label as well as to use for calculations in subsequent views.

I can print the snapshot in the console, but when I assign it to a text label, the label is blank. Just to be clear, I don't want to populate a table with this data. I want to pull specific data from the database and show it in a label and also use it for making calculations.

Here's my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getIncome()
}

func getIncome() {
    ref.child("Users").child("Family1").child("Income").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        print(snapshot)     // replace this with textLabel or other item
        let m = snapshot.value as? String
        self.textLabel.text = m
    })
}
```

And here's my JSON tree from Firebase:

[image: Screenshot of Firebase Database Structure]

Comment: what format do you want the label to look like afterwards? eg. "Income: 1234, Name: Bob"?

Comment: It was going to be a concatenation: "Your income is \(textLabel)." Then I was going to use the data to do some further calculations. So I just want an Int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your database has `Income` stored as an integer, so when you are trying to cast `snapshot.value` to a string it returns nil since it is an integer. So you first have to cast it to an `Int` then you can concatenate it to a string.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users").child("Family1").child("Income")

ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    if let income = snapshot.value as? Int {

        self.textLabel.text = "Your income is: \(income)"
    }
})
```

The label then shows `Your income is: 456789`

#### Example

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var calculateButton: UIButton!

    var income: Int?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        calculateButton.isHidden = true // Prevents user tapping it until we have data from firebase

        getIncome { (income) in

            self.income = income

            if let income = income {

                self.textLabel.text = "Your income is: \(income)"
            }

            self.calculateButton.isHidden = false
        }
    }

    func getIncome(completion: @escaping (Int?)->()){

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users").child("Family1").child("Income")

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            completion(snapshot.value as? Int)
        })
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "CalculateSegue" {

            guard

                let income = income,

                let vc = segue.destination as? CalculateViewController

            else {

                return
            }

            vc.income = income
        }

    }
}

class CalculateViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var incomeLabel:UILabel!

    var income: Int!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.incomeLabel.text = "\(income)"
    }
}
```

[image: Storyboard]

[image: ViewController]

[image: CalculateViewController]

Comment: I see. I had read that Firebase stored all data as AnyObject, and thus I had to reassign values. I didn't know Firebase stored Ints. So the second part of my question was, how do I use that data to perform my calculations? Do I just assign it to another variable?

Comment: It depends on where you are doing your calculations. Since this firebase request is done asynchronously, you would want to wait for the request to finish before doing any calculations. So I would have a function that takes the income as a parameter, and just call it from the firebase block.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's exactly what I want to do, but I don't know how to accomplish that. All my efforts result in nil, or blank, or errors.

This is the workflow: the user inputs an income, and then the app uses that income to do all sorts of different calcuations in different views. It becomes a constant (literally) throughout the app. I was just going to call that parameter for each view, but perhaps a global function would be better?

Comment: By different views do you mean view controllers or subviews?

Comment: That's the part that I'm just not getting: the whole 'asynchronous' bit. I keep reading up on it, but I'm stumped. Should I be creating a function that requests a snapshot, or do a query, or what? I tried a 'func getIncomeNumber() -> Int, but I've run into the same problem again. Errors and nil values.

Comment: Different view controllers. The app has several different view controllers, and I'd like to use the same value to do my calculations for each of the view controllers.

Comment: Are you using buttons to segue to other view controllers?

Comment: Yes, I use buttons to segue to different controllers. Why?

Comment: Well, it would be best to disable them until Firebase has retrieved the income.

Comment: It sounds like I have more research to do. I don't understand the whole asynchronous thing, nor do I understand the Firebase language. I thought pulling single data points from a database would be relatively simple, but it doesn't make sense, and it's frustratingly complicated. [end rant]

Comment: I have added some code above that should help you understand what you need to do.

Comment: Excellent! I'll take it for a test drive tomorrow.

Comment: Everything works! Super stoked. And I like how you hid the button until the data was collected. Nice. Just out of curiosity, though, I'm wondering if pushing the data from one controller to the next is the best way forward? I'm looking for best practices, and want to make sure I'm doing things right. Is that preferable to creating, say, a "global variable"? Or is it in fact a global variable because it's on the database and can be called at any time?

Comment: Passing variables via a segue is the recommended practice. Global variables are unnecessary and can be quite troublesome and it it best not to keep on calling firebase for the same data, that will just slow the app down. So the way I have it above it the best way of doing it.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmmm... I tried using the variable 'income' in some calculations, and it keeps returning 'nil'. I'm confused what I've done wrong. Sometimes it comes back as 'nil', and other times it comes back as 'optional(125009)'. So it seems that I'm using the variable 'income' before it's done getting it from the database, but I thought the code you gave me made sure the variable was good to go. What am I missing?

Comment: `    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prototypeCell", for: indexPath) as! Setup106TableViewCell
        let (dailyHabitName, dailyHabitMultiplier, dailyHabitConsistencyBonus, dailyHabitEditable) = dailyChores[indexPath.row]
        cell.titleLabel.text = dailyHabitName
        cell.detailLabel.text = "\(Double(income!) * 0.00125)"
        return cell
    }
`

Comment: It is the `func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` method that handles the income variable for the next view controller, not the  `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`. So if anything is wrong, it will be in that function.

Comment: Ah, that's the problem. I want to use the variable in the CURRENT view controller. How do I do that?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. The way I have done it in my answer seems to work with no problems. What variable are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, snap! I think I figured it out. When working with an async database, I think I have to wait until the database finishes loading before trying to display data or do calculations based off that data. Perhaps there's a term for that or a better way to do this, but here's my solution.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prototypeCell", for: indexPath) as! Setup106TableViewCell

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let (dailyChoreName, dailyChoreMultiplier, _, _) = dailyChores[indexPath.row]
        cell.titleLabel.text = dailyChoreName
        if income != nil {
            cell.detailLabel.text = "\(Int(round((Double(income!) * nationalAvg * mpsMagicNumber * Double(dailyChoreMultiplier) / 52) / 5) * 5))"
        } else {
            tableView.reloadData()      // this was the issue
        }

    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        let (dailyHabitName, dailyHabitMultiplier, _, _) = dailyHabits[indexPath.row]
        cell.titleLabel.text = dailyHabitName
        if income != nil {
            cell.detailLabel.text = "\(Int(round((Double(income!) * nationalAvg * mpsMagicNumber * Double(dailyHabitMultiplier) / 52) / 5) * 5))"
        } else {
            tableView.reloadData()      // this was the issue
        }

    } else {
        let (weeklyChoreName, weeklyChoreMultiplier, _, _) = weeklyChores[indexPath.row]
        cell.titleLabel.text = weeklyChoreName
        if income != nil {
            cell.detailLabel.text = "\(Int(round((Double(income!) * nationalAvg * mpsMagicNumber * Double(weeklyChoreMultiplier) / 52) / 50) * 50))"
        } else {
            tableView.reloadData()      // this was the issue
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

I just have to add in the 'tableView.reloadData` parameter before proceeding. Nice.